# Rspec: Fully Qualified Cass Names vs Module Namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've always fully qualified my class names, even if the namespace is large, while writing specs, like this:

```rb
::Rspec.describe ::Foo::Bar do
end
```

However, recently I've seen some specs written like this instead:

```
module Foo
  ::Rspec.describe ::Bar do
  end
end
```

Is there a technical reason to prefer one over the other? The second method feels like we're needlessly polluting the `Foo` namespace with out rspec code, but it really shouldn't collide with anything because we're just calling the `::Rspec.describe` method with a classname argument and a block of code.

Comment: I have always preferred the first style and have never seen the second in use.

Comment: Rubocop keeps yelling at me to unnest the namespaces, which I do, usually. I ran into a weird problem with Pundit, an authorization gem, where it had random trouble resolving the nested modules, so I had to go back to the flat version in those classes. 99.9% of the time, I believe it's personal preference.